# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4: Select custom week automatically while moving the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

The Datepicker can only select the row to which my mouse is pointing.
Like this:

```
    .bootstrap-datepicker-widget tr:hover {
    background-color: #808080;
}
```

Here is the working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/owos/1mzhwykv/

However, I want to highlight the week from Thursday to Wednesday.The week is split into two rows, and that makes `tr:hover` not work.

Comment: do you want do this for all the weeks or specific week only?

Comment: @GeethW for all the weeks

Comment: it would be quite simple if not for Bootstrap generating it on the fly each time http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/5psu9tf8/

Comment: @AndrewBone Thanks, it works well.

Comment: @AndrewBone I tried to do some improvement based on your code,  however, after changing the datetimepicker into a input text, function `hover` didn't work like before. Dosen't the days in the popup have the css class "day"?

Comment: @laxus I think the picker is generated on the fly, meaning it doesn't exist when the onhovers are added.

Comment: @laxus https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/1mzhwykv/1/ quick little hack to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to style the right cells with JQuery

```
var weekStart = 4,
  selectColor = "#ccc";

weekSelect = function() {
  $(".day").hover(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    if (index < weekStart) {
      prevSlice = index;
      nextSlice = weekStart - index - 1;
      prevWeek = 7;
      nextWeek = 0;
    } else {
      prevSlice = index - weekStart;
      nextSlice = 6 - index;
      prevWeek = weekStart;
      nextWeek = weekStart;
    }
    $(this).parent().next().children().slice(0, nextWeek).css('background-color', selectColor);
    $(this).parent().prev().children().slice(weekStart, prevWeek).css('background-color', selectColor);
    $(this).prevAll().slice(0, prevSlice).css('background-color', selectColor);
    $(this).css('background-color', selectColor);
    $(this).nextAll().slice(0, nextSlice).css('background-color', selectColor);
  }, function() {
    $(this).parent().prev().children().slice(0, prevWeek).css('background-color', '');
    $(this).prevAll().slice(0, prevSlice).css('background-color', '');
    $(this).css('background-color', '');
    $(this).nextAll().slice(0, nextSlice).css('background-color', '');
    $(this).parent().next().children().slice(0, nextWeek).css('background-color', '');
  });
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/1mzhwykv/1/

Comment: It's so nice of you. By the way, I tried your code and found that it would not work after changing the `viewDate`, so I added ```    $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.update', function(e) {
     weekSelect();
    });``` in the code.